# I'm getting an undefined reference error to something that isn't there

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-errors, undefined-reference

When I try to compile this code

```
Analysis2::Analysis2() //line 13
{
    Seconds_v = 0;    //Seconds_v and Seconds_t are both of type int 
    Seconds_t = 0;    //and declared in header
}
```

I get this error

analysis2.cpp:13: undefined reference to `FileParameters::FileParameters()'

Why is it giving me that undefined reference?  FileParameters is a class included in Analysis2 and there is a FileParameters object defined in the Analysis2 header file if that helps.

Comment: Have you include it in your linked objects?

Comment: I both included the FileParameters header and declared a FileParameters variable that is initialized in another method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have constructor, every member variable is automatically default-constructed if you don't explicitly construct it in the initializer list. Your code above automatically expands to:

```
Analysis2::Analysis2() : mFileParams(), Seconds_v(), Seconds_t() // line 13
{
    Seconds_v = 0;    //Seconds_v and Seconds_t are both of type int 
    Seconds_t = 0;    //and declared in header
}
```

And if you didn't implement the default constructor of `FileParameters` yet, or don't even have an accessible one, that's the error you get.

Comment: Thanks!  I forgot to delete my FileParameters constructor from its header file even though i got rid of it in the code

Answer (score 0):

The Analysis2 class (bloody awful name, BTW) is probably implemented using FileParameters. You need to link the objects for both classes - simply including the header is not enough. But to be sure, we would need to see more code.

Comment: Yeah...I inherited the code from someone else and I'm working on breaking it into classes...they had it all in one file.  I'll fix the names when I finalize it